# Chainlink Keepers - Multiple Upkeeps in a Single Contract

Tags: solidity, chainlink

From ChainLink docs [Here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/compatible-contracts/), I know we can create upkeeps using the `checkUpkeep` and `performupkeep` functions.

Is it possible to create multiple upkeep checks and performs in the same contract? may I know how?

or do we need to create separate upkeep contracts registered to perform different upkeeps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create multiple `checkUpkeep()` and `performUpkeep()` functions in a single contract.

What you can do is [register multiple upkeeps](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/register-upkeep/) to the same contract and have each upkeep pass in a different `checkData` argument. Within the `checkUpkeep()` function you can now have multiple paths, that depend on what `checkData` is passed through. Each path can start upkeep based on different conditions. At the end of every execution path, make sure to return the same `checkData` as `performData`, which will go into `performUpkeep()`.

Now in your `performUpkeep()` function you can also have different paths that correspond to each `performData`.

For example, [check out this gist](https://gist.github.com/ZakAyesh/5048ecc72f545a898179a4f85e2947fa).

For that contract, I registered 3 different upkeeps, and in each one passed a different checkData: 0x01, 0x02, and 0x03, corresponding to the different upkeep execution paths in my contract. For example: [image]